# replace List.foreach to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm new to LINQ and doing some experiments with it.

Sorry if it is a duplicate but I cant seem to find proper guide (for me) to it

I want to replace this code :

```
DataTable table
List<string> header = new List<string>();
table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col => header.Add(col.ColumnName));
```

with something LINQ like:

```
var LINQheader = from mycol in table.Columns select mycol.ColumnName;
LINQheader.tolist();
```

but it doesn't even compile.
what I want Is not a one line solution but would like some logic to understand how construct it with more complicated environments (Like choosing many node in XML with some logic)

Comment: Isn't the reason it doesn't compile the fact you have `table.column` in your linq statement rather than `table.Columns`?

Comment: @DoctorMick of course you right it was just a typo (I didn't copy it from the code but rewrite it in the question )
Edited the question

Comment: It still doesn't compile as the Linq is case-sensitive, see my answer.

Comment: @VMAtm you are correct , I will edit it .
but the question here is not about syntax so it is of less importance :)

Comment: @LordTitiKaka Can you please provide the compilation error? Because of it's really confusing, what exactly didn't compile.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the original code

```
table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col => header.Add(col.ColumnName));
```

Why `Cast` used?
because it allows you to treat `DataColumnCollection` items as a `DataColumn` not an object.

Why `ToList` used?
becuase it converts your `IEnumerable` to `List` and allows you to call `ForEach` because this function is special method that exists in `List` class.

Why `ForEach` used?
because it allows you to do what you want for each element on the list (in your case it adds column name of each column to another list(`header`)).

**Simplified version:**

now assume you want to add column names to `header` where they starts with "Student"
you can write something like this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
List<string> header = new List<string>();

foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
{
    if (col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Id")) // you can remove this line if you want to add all of them
       header.Add(col.ColumnName);
}
```

you can also use this

```
table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(col =>
    {
        if (col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Id"))
            header.Add(col.ColumnName)
    });
```

or

```
var headers = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Where(col => col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Id"))
        .Select(col => col.ColumnName);

header.AddRange(headers);
```

Comment: Actually are the answers are good , but yours (I think) is more informative on and the logic behind

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Aggregate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this:

```
var header = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Aggregate(new List<string>(), (list, col) => { list.Add(col.ColumnName); return list; });
```

In general, Linq allows for retrieval and transformation of sequences of data from data sources.  What you want to do in this question is to iterate over a sequence and return an immediate result.  That isn't the primary focus of Linq, but there are methods that perform [tasks like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), including `Aggregate()`, `Average()`, `Count()`, `Max()` and so on.

Comment: what I want Is not a one line solution but would like some logic to understand how construct it with more complicated environments

Comment: @dotctor - are you the OP?  If you could explain what you would like to do, maybe I could help more.

Comment: I just pasted part of the OP for you, I want you to help the one who asked the question, I think understanding `Aggregate` is more difficult than `ForEach`.

Comment: @dotctor what you mean when say _more dificult_?

Answer (score 2):

```
var LINQheader = from mycol in table.column select mycol.ColumnName;
LINQheader.tolist();
```

This will not compile as there is no such property in `DataTable` as `column`, there is only `Columns`, and you have to use `.Cast()` method as they are not implementing right interface (see @Uriil's answer).

Try this:

```
var LINQheader = from mycol in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  select mycol.ColumnName;
LINQheader.tolist();
```

If you want to use wrap it in an extension method, you can do it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetHeaderColumns (this DataTable dataTable) 
{
    if (dataTable == null || !dataTable.Columns.Any())
    {
        yield break;
    }
    foreach (var col in dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
    {
        yield return col.ColumnName;
    }
}
```

Comment: for more consistent implement it also as extension method for DataTable :-)

Comment: @Grundy Yes, my lord!

Comment: extension methods must be static functions inside static classes

Comment: @dotctor Yes, added `static` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Columns.Add("A");
        tbl.Columns.Add("B");

        var p = from DataColumn col in tbl.Columns select col.ColumnName;

        foreach(string a in p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
```

Here little code example. If you want to be `List<string>`, use `ToList()`.

**EDIT:**

Like @Grundy says you missing to specify type of the col, which is DataColumn.

```
List<string> columnList = (from DataColumn mycol in table.Columns select mycol.ColumnName).ToList();
```

Here this will be your one line.

Comment: please add to your answer that your code work because you specify type `DataColumn` for `col` variable in select clause

Comment: yep, i think so too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple select like

```
DataTable table;
IEnumerable<string> header = from mycol in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                             select mycol.ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems, which requires workaround:

1. ForEach is List specifict method, so can can not translate it into LINQ
2. LINQ is for data selection, aggregation, but not for data
   modification
3. `table.Columns`, returns `DataColumnCollection`, which does not
   implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so you will have to cast it anyway:

   ```
   var LINQheader = from mycol in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                    select name.ColumnName;
   ```